# Changes made in the Html files are not reflected in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an application in MVC3.

 I have a Table named HobbyMasters with fields:

```
HobbyName
InformationUrl
```

On the left hand side of the page the links are displayed fetched through database
and on the right handside on click of the link an url is loaded in the Iframe

I have wrote the following Code in View:

```
//To fetch all the HobbyNames and display it as links:

  <ul>                       
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <li >@Html.ActionLink(item.HobbyName, "Hobbies")
   </li>
}</ul>  
 <div>         
 <iframe id="iframe" frameborder="0" src="@Url.Content("~/HTML/Dancing.htm")" style="width: 100%; height: 700px;"></iframe>
                     </div>
```

//Ajax function to load the url on click

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('a').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var filename = $(this).text();
          var Hobbyurl = '@Url.Action("FetchUrlByHobbyName")';
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: Hobbyurl,
              data: { data: filename },
              success: function (returndata) {
                  $('iframe').attr('src', returndata);     
              }
          });
      });
  });
  </script>
```

//Function To fetch the url from the database:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FetchUrlByHobbyName(string data)
    {
        HobbyMasters hobbymaster = new HobbyHomeService().FetchHobbyMasterByHobbyName(data);
        string url=hobbymaster.InformationUrl;
        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return Json(url);
        return View();
    }
```

Everything is working fine.But the problem is that my Html page does not reflect the changes i make in it.
I have copied my entire code just to show whethr at any place i have used any session information bcz of that it is happening..
Even i deleted the file stil the same file is coming...
please suggest me what shud i do

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache to see if the browser has cached the URL you previously looked at?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear which file is not getting updated.
 I would do a Ctrl + F5(Refresh) if my html or script is not updated.

Comment: My Html page is not loading properly i did ctrl+f5 but that doesnot work for me..the only thing that works is if i put manually the version information: HTML/dancing.htm?version=1 inside the InformationUrl in the database the it gets updated but i dont want this i am looking for some better method.